Alternative to xfce when connecting to Ubuntu using Windows remote Desktop
I have a work supplied laptop (I am not an admin and therefore am limited in what I can install) which I use from home with two external monitors. I want to be able to connect to my laptop (dual boot with Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS) using Remote Desktop Connection.
When I connect using Remote Desktop Connection I get an xrdp popup window and am prompted for Session (default Xorg), username and password.
When I connect I am in an XFCE environment, this is usable but I would prefer something more like the default enviroment when I use the laptop directly (which I believe is Gnome).
How can I achieve this?
-- I followed the instructions in the suggested question but that did not change the behavior when I got logged in (still in the xfce environment)

More information is needed, specifically which Ubuntu.  While standard Ubuntu uses Gnome for the GUI, XUbuntu uses XFCE.

Possible duplicate of How to login to the Ubuntu (not GNOME) session on a remote server using xRDP?. You may want to login to the "Ubuntu" session rather than XFCE session (assuming your OS is Ubuntu with XFCE, not Xubuntu).

The version of Ubuntu is 24.04.1 LTS
